# android timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp

hi i have a small question please i am new to android and have a date and time stamp 
which looks like this yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

and i want to insert it into an sqlite table then read it back and compare it to the current time

any suggestions or examples

i found "`SimpleDateFormat`" but was not sure how to use it....?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using `Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis()`?  It's just the `long` representation of a date in milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970.  Great thing is your data is being stored in a format agnostic way.  Just when you need to display it use SimpleDateFormat however you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you would do:

```
String myDate = new String("your date");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(myDate);
date.getTime(); //fetch the time as milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970
```

Answer (score 3):

Try use
`System.currentTimeMillis();`
its undepend from Calender.